# Google Calendar API iOS Quickstart Automatic Sign In

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, xcode9

Got the Quickstart App working.  The first time you run it, you have to sign in to Google.  Is there a way to hard code the username and password to automatically sign in?  I'd like to not have to show the Google Button, every time the app runs and sign in at all.  I've searched the site and web and have found any help.  Any ideas?

Comment: To get things straight - you would want all your users to see (and possibly edit) the same calendar?

Comment: Yes, this is for a very small business (3 people) and we share the calendar for our job schedules.

Comment: For that you can use the Service Account pattern. It's a different flow of OAuth. Documentation and examples are given in the docs (I don't know if there's anything specific to iOS but certainly you can adapt from what's there and understand the pattern).